# SQL Query to calculate datetime difference between 2 rows (checkin/checkout)

Tags: sql, date-difference

i am using a microsoft access database from an attendance program. I want to do my own Attendance website but i am having problems creating the sql query.

i have a table with the columns below:

```
USERID | CHECKTIME | CHECKTYPE
```

where userid is a number,
checktime is date/time and
checktype determines if the user CHECKIN (I) or CHECKOUT(O).

Sample data:

```
5 | 26/01/2017 14:20:00 | I
5 | 26/01/2017 20:10:00 | O
6 | 26/01/2017 08:05:00 | I
6 | 26/01/2017 17:31:00 | O
```

How can i show the user, the date, and the time difference between the 2 rows? (checkin and checkout)?

thanks in advance,
Philip.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to do the following steps:

- Divide the table into two small tables based on the I/O value.
- Join the two table on the userid field.
- Select the difference from the result of the Join.

This is an example (the main table is named user_table):

```
SELECT userid, B.CHECKTIME - A.CHECKTIME FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE CHECKTYPE = 'I') as A
    NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE CHECKTYPE = 'O') as B
    USING(userid)
```

I hope you have understood the base mechanism.

Comment: I used your query, but i added "where b.userid = a.userid" instead of using (or ON) since you don't have a join outside the from clause. But still i do not get any results from the query

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select a.userid, a.checktime - b.checktime
  from yourtable a
  join yourtable b on a.userid = b.userid
 where a.checktype = 'I'
   and b.checktype = 'O'
```

Comment: it returns minus results. for instance: 5 | -3700 etc